Guidance on creating a rotating string of cylinders
I'm new to Blender and already trying to achieve super technical stuff! lol! Take a look at the DNA looking strand of rods in the hero image of this website. https://www.neoculturalcouture.com/ I'm trying to recreate it. I've managed to get the row of cylinders, but I can't figure out how to offset them from each other.
I have tried the Screw modifier, but it either creates a disc or a tunnel spiraling inwards. I also tried creating a bezier curve but had no luck at all.
Would really appreciate some guidance. Thanks in advance! :)


Add an empty object.
Rotate the empty by the angle you want to be the difference between 2 consequent cylinders.
Add an Array modifier to the cylinder.
Use the constant offset to control the distance between the cylinders and the object offset with the empty as the target to control the rotation.

That should be it.

should also have to apply scale on the cylinder?   could also offset the Empty from 0/0/0 instead of setting array offset.

@james_t the question doesn't say anything about changing the scale.

in creating the object the user probably started with the cylinder and then modified it as would be indicated by the reference picture.  Without applying scale, the other elements in the array might look like the original cylinder instead of the modified one.

@james_t Usually answers given on this platform are going to assume knowledge of the rest of Blender for the sake of brevity. Most answers are meant to explain one specific problem and how to solve it, not give a complete step-by-step tutorial about how to do everything.

Hi guys, thanks for your input. I eventually did it manually by duplicating the cylinder and adjusting the x and y axis by pre-determined variables. Now I am trying to render it, but it comes out all jerky. In the preview it looks fine. I've set my animation preferences to linear and followed this youtube tutorial, but it's coming out all jerky https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BJekfgtmpi8

can I share a file to show what it looks like?

I figured it out after reading a Reddit post. I exported the png sequence and uploaded it to after effects and did it in there
